# PHP Foreach Not Showing Correct Output?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm having trouble with my `foreach` loop.

On my script:

```
$Tags = "PHP,HTML,CSS,Java";
$ExplodedVar = explode(",", $Tags);
print_r($ExplodedVar);
foreach ($ExplodedVar AS $NewStr)
{
    echo "<a href='#>$NewStr</a>,";
}
```

The `print_r($ExplodedVar);`

Is displaying the correct output of:

> `Array ( [0] => PHP [1] => HTML [2] => CSS [3] => Java )`

`foreach` loop outposts only HTML & Java

Comment: Your HTML markup may be what's causing your errors.

Comment: Changed to:  echo "<a href=\'#\'>$NewStr</a>, and works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the close quote `'` of href.

```
foreach ($ExplodedVar AS $NewStr)
{
  echo "<a href='#'>$NewStr</a>,";
}
```

And if the data is user input, then you need to sanitize the data.

```
foreach ($ExplodedVar AS $NewStr)
{
  echo "<a href='#'>". htmlspecialchars($NewStr)."</a>,";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss one single quote on hash :

```
echo "<a href='#'>$NewStr</a>,";
```